# Отступ в блоке со скролом

Tags: прокрутка, css

Такая проблема:

```
<div id="block">
   ...
</div>

#block { overflow-y:auto; padding-bottom:30px; }
```

Нужно блоку со скролом зделать отступ внизу, что-бы контент внутри него не доставал до конца блока. padding-bottom не делает этого. То есть отступ есть, но контент скролиться сквозь него.

Answer (score 2):

[@godan](/users/12165/godan), а что если контент заключить в абзац и задать у него необходимый margin?

Answer (score 0):

Дк всё правильно.
Чтобы без костылей, нужно вложить ещё один блок

```css
#block {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.holder {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="holder">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```